# Can you import a visio sharepoint workflow template directly into Visual studio without using Designer?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, visio, sharepoint-workflow

We are trying to determine if it is possible to import a workflow directly from Visio to Visual Studio without using SharePoint Designer. A comment here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/92095335-3ac5-4568-b87d-bc17d147cb11 indicates that the UML versions of Visio and Visual Studio do not match. Is this still the case?

Would we be able to use Visio 2013 to go directly from Visio to Visual Studio? If this can be done, does anyone have the steps to do so?

Thank you in advance.